# mplot3d axis labels and colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, mplot3d

I have a 3D projection plot which is really a collection of 2D slices of some value. I also shade the underlying area with:

```
    ax.add_collection3d(plt.fill_between())
```

[image]
I have a couple of related questions:

1) The plot looks fine but the axis labels look messed up - they are rendered on top of the tick labels. How can I space them out a bit?

2) How can I choose what camera angle is rendered? (I'm using Jupiter notebook).

3) The background of the plot (behind the grid, not the grid color itself) is this light blueish grey. how can make that white?

Thanks!

Comment: for the view, `ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-35)` (see the bottom of http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/2dcollections3d_demo.html)

Comment: your third question is addressed in many places on SO and the MPL docs.

Comment: thank you guys. any clues about the overlapping axis labels?

Answer (score 0):

for number 1) ax.set_xlabel() has a labelpad parameters that can be set to any number of pixels.